# Ruby on Rails app not connecting

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't connect to my localhost using Ruby on Rails.  I've made fresh installs (even using explicit commands like `rails new test_app -d mysql`) but it never connects to the page.  When I try localhost:3000 there's just a white page and the Firefox loading icon doesn't stop.  When I first installed it, the startup screen loaded fine - but after adding resources it just hangs.  I can add resources to the database fine using `rake db:migrate`.  Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: root
  database: limetree
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

The test and production environments are the same setup.  The weird thing is that I can add resources/tables to my database using the console - it's just my browser doesn't seem to  be able to connect to the database using the app's controllers.  I also think it might be a routing problem.  The only line I changed in my routes.rb is:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Does anybody know why my Rails app isn't loading?

**UPDATE:**

Because I was running out-of-date versions (Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.1) I reinstalled everything from scratch with the latest software.  There was a minor issue with the rake gem which was resolved by reinstalling it.  Everything now works fine.

Comment: when you try localhost:3000, is there any logs displayed by rails server?

Answer (score 0):

try `password: "root"` in your config file

Comment: No change. I don't think that'll be the issue because the `rails generate scaffold` is able to connect to the database.

Comment: Did your restart server after edit config? I have this problem 3 or 4 times in my practice, and every time password was not be quoted

Comment: By config file, I assume you mean database.yml yeah? I've restarted the server with no change. I also tried running the server in different environments and it still doesn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Got to http://localhost:3000, open the file **log/development.log** in your Rails application directory, and look if there is any useful message.

Comment: All there is is a few lines that show where I generated my test resource and: `Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Sep 11 17:43:45 +0100 2011`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MySQL server is actually running. You could try to use this in the routes file:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set a home page, make sure you have a controller called 'home' and it has an action called 'index'.